# Windows CE Registry Setting - Never Power Off

Tags: windows-mobile, registry

I have a unique industrial application where I do not want the Windows CE device to ever power off (powering off cuts the wireless connection, resulting in a looooong delay re-establishing a link to the server).  The issue: a hard reset removes the "never turn off" setting of the device, allowing it to sleep.  Avoiding a hard reset is not an option, as the devices sometimes require them.

What is the *registry key* that controls this?  The idea is, with a registry file, the device will merge the key into the system at boot, negating the need for manually setting this.

---

To save time, the answer was in a comment below, so I've re-pasted it here for reference:

---

The registry entry is: [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Power\Timeouts] "BattSuspendTimeout" = dword:00000000

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is the device?

With Symbol brand scanners running CE you have to use a special program (available for free) from symbol that basicly takes a snap shot of the device - then you set your settings for what you want and it takes another snapshot - it then writes the code to reset all the registry settings for you in case of a cold boot.

With more info on the device I may be able to help more.

Comment: It is indeed a Symbol 4090 series handheld.

Comment: do you have a link to that tool?

Comment: All my info on that is on my laptop at work...I will check this Monday morning - if no answer yet I will post what I have.

If you have not already checked out http://support.symbol.com - that is the support site.

For the life of me I cannot remember what the software is called...but I will have it Monday.

--Joe

Comment: Also - symbol provides very good phone tech support - I have never had to wait more than 5 mins - 1.800.653.5350 - that is where I got the original link and walk through from.

Comment: Found it - Got to thinking that it might be in a old email from Motorola:
http://support.symbol.com/support/search.do?cmd=displayKC&docType=kc&externalId=11297&sliceId=&dialogID=7084242&stateId=0%200%207078620

It is called RemoteCapture.

Let me know if you need any help using it.

Comment: It supports the following devices:
MC50 
MC1000 
MC3000 
MC9000 
PDT8100 
PPT8800 
MC70 
MC9060 
MC9090 
MC3090 
WT4090 
VC5090 
MC35

--sorry about the multiple comments....sorta scatterbrained tonight!

Comment: Last comment - I promise:
There is a newer version:
http://support.symbol.com/support/search.do?cmd=displayKC&docType=kc&externalId=11754&sliceId=&dialogID=102502223&stateId=1%200%20102490840

Comment: The "tool" could also be Remote Registry Editor.  It ships with eVC, Studio 03, Studio 05 and Studio 08 and can save out an entire registry key.

Comment: The registry entry is: [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Power\Timeouts]
"BattSuspendTimeout" = dword:00000000

Comment: Also the brute force approach that I have used for this sort of thing is to use remote registry editor to export the registry of the device, set the setting, export the registry again, then windiff the 2 files to see what the differences are :) You can see what has changed and it works for any device

Answer (score 6):

Try this code:

```
REGEDIT4

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Power\Timeouts]
 "BattSuspendTimeout"=dword:0
```